# Eclipse 3.8 - Prevent File Name Truncating in Editor Tabs

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I have want seems like it should be a simple question but I keep striking out...

In Eclipse 3.8 / STS 3.1, how do I stop Eclipse from truncating the file names in the editor tabs.  I can't tell which tab is which.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Under `Window`-> `Preferences` go to `General` -> `Editors`.
The last point should be "Close editors automatically", and you can specify a number.

If you check this, the least recently used editor will be closed when the given amount of opened editors is reached. That way the open editors don't take up so much space, and the possibility of truncated names is reduced.
You can always quickly search and open resources with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, so there is no need to have them open all the time.

Of course it can't be guaranteed to always show the complete name. If there is not enough space, what do you expect Eclipse to do?

Comment: I was hoping that it would show the whole file name even if that meant it had to hide more tabs.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it does make sense - this is what one would expect Eclipse to do. Also, why not just add more lines for tabs, like IDEA? It's so amazing that all of this isn't a no-brainer. Especially given the enormous length of JEE class names.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [solution](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=32789).

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=32789.

I have tried it with Eclipse Kepler 4.3 SR1

Comment: Did it work? Sure didn't with Eclipse Luna SR2 (4.4.2)

Comment: Would be great if you could explain what's found at the link given, just in case it's not reachable.

Answer (score -4):

you need to set eclipse Threme.

Under Window-> Preferences go to General ->Appearance

Threme: Classic

Comment: Well, no, this doesn't help.