# eclipse - how to control either the width of the editor tab or length of the filename string?

Tags: eclipse, editor

I am scratching my head on this - when there are multiple files starting with the same character sequences open, eclipse displays 4 tabs with pretty much the same sequence because the string-length for filenames on the editor tab is 15. How can I change this so the full filename is displayed?

For example - So, when I have multiple files with names "PSScaleProtocol.java", PSScaleProtocolTest or PSScaleProtocolDaemon, all I get to see on three tabs is "PSScaleProtoc".

I am using "Kepler" on a mac and key-word grepping on **/Applications/Eclipse Standard 4.3.1/Eclipse Standard 4.3.1.app/Contents/Profile/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.3.1.v20130911-1000** did not yield any results.

any pointers appreciated.

PS: I just found this on stackoverflow, doesnt help me though - [Eclipse 3.8 - Prevent File Name Truncating in Editor Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15295271/eclipse-3-8-prevent-file-name-truncating-in-editor-tabs)

Comment: Moving the mouse to the editor tab generates a tool tip with the directory path and name of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can change the CSS that renders the tab to be a more narrow font or to be a smaller size.

Source: [How to change the font size of the Eclipse editor tab's title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317674/how-to-change-the-font-size-of-eclipse-editor-tabs-title)

Comment: I tried this - the font is reduced. However, the string length is still 15. I followed the instructions on https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=32789 and stuck the values for " org.eclipse.ui/EDITOR_MINIMUM_CHARACTERS=80" in plugin_customization.ini and no luck. There are 2 mentions of the path,  org.eclipse.ui and  org.eclipse.ui.workbench, no luck

Comment: I used comments from the following thread - http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/172927/ and provided my own plugin_customization.ini and still no luck

Comment: @daazakali In which file path is "EDITOR_MINIMUM_CHARACTERS" located?

Comment: @user1803551, On a Mac, The path is, /Applications/Eclipse Standard 4.3.1/Eclipse Standard 4.3.1.app/Contents/Profile and the file is ./plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.3.1.v20130911-1000/plugin_customization.ini

Comment: as i mentioned, I also provided my own plugin customization file using this bash script, STILL DID NOT WORK, #!/bin/bash
/Applications/"Eclipse Standard 4.3.1"/"Eclipse Standard 4.3.1.app"/Contents/Profile/eclipse -pluginCustomization ~/Desktop/plugin_customization.ini&

Comment: @daazakali Did you try my answer?

Comment: @user1803551, Yeah, I tried, see my comment below. I already have set it to false

Answer (score 0):

> How can I change this so the full filename is displayed?

In the folder `*eclipse install path*\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_*version*\css` open the `.css` file for you theme and edit the following property:

`swt-simple: true` to `swt-simple: false` located under `MPartStack`.

Comment: It is already set to false, here is the blurb of my MPartStack. Note, I recently edited this section to set "swt-mru-visible" to true. 

 .MPartStack {
           font-size: 9;
           swt-simple: false;
          swt-mru-visible: true;
  }

Comment: @daazakali What theme did you do this for? I'm on Windows and it works for me without changing anything else.

Comment: @daazakali But which eclipse theme are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I checked and found that it was the theme "mac"  was being used. I changed it to "classic" theme and the string length of the filename went up from 15 5to 20.

Comment: @daazakali I can't load those themes, only Windows ones which all respect `swt-simple` property. Try setting `swt-tab-renderer` to null.

Comment: I tried setting this to null in the default theme, mac theme and even switched to "default theme" - none have worked so far. With the default theme, the string-length has fallen back to 15. On the Classic Theme, i noted it was 20 characters